# parse template in view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, html-parsing

I am new to Codeigniter. I created a template for form and want to parse it within view file. It is parsing but it echos parsed form on the top of the page, not where I want. I am not using template for whole page. I want to render peace of page using parser.
Here is my parser:

```
<form action = {action}>

<select name = {input_name}>
    {options}
        <option value = {val}>{name}</option>
    {/options}

</select>
```

And I called this template from my view.php using this function:

```
$this->parser->parse('form_templates/vehicle_category.php', $form_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I should look into the parser library. There is a third parameter for parse function which tells return result instead of echoing. Updated code is:

```
$this->parser->parse('form_templates/vehicle_category.php', $form_data, true); //true for return default is false
```